# How to add delay to a running function on click of a div

Tags: jquery, delay

I have a function called autoSlide which animates the margin of a div to show a sprite of images into a img tag into it

```
function marginCalc(){
        var getmargin = parseInt($("#scrollimage").css('margin-left'));
        var usemargin =  -1350 ;
        var increment= getmargin+usemargin;
        if(increment <= -2750)
        {
        $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':0},1000);
        }
        else{
        $('#scrollimage').animate({'margin-left': ++increment},1000);
        }
    }
function autoSlide(){
        setInterval(function() {
        marginCalc();
        }, 5000);
        }
```

And when a div is clicked it resets the margin to show the respective image

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#Image1").click(function(){
                $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':0});
        });

        $("#Image2").click(function(){
                $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':-1350});
        });

       autoSlide();

       });
```

My problem is when the div is clicked it scrolls back to the respective image but the autoSlide functions keeps on running, I want to stop for 3 seconds after the div is clicked for the user to see the image, then again keep running the autoSlide function from there.

How to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple demo for timeout:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/czf6m/)
try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#Image1").click(function(){
                $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':0});
        });

        $("#Image2").click(function(){
                $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':-1350});
        });

    var timeout;
    if(timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
    }

    timeout = setTimeout( autoSlide, 3000);


       });
```

Comment: Wont that take me to the part of the image after 3 seconds, i dont want that , i want the click function to show me image instantly but the autoSlide function should pause for 3 secs and run as it is

Comment: you want a pause before the call to the function autoSlide?

Comment: Sorry Alessandro that didnt work, may be my question is not clear. I will try to explain.
the autoSlide function keeps on running and manipulating the containing div (overflow:hidden) , so the the sprite slides left and the portion to the left is seen.Clicking on #Image1 sets the margin to 0 so the first portion of the slide is visible. But if i do this at 2 secs, the autoSlide changes the margin after 1 sec so the user can see the  image for 1 sec only. How to pause after the autoSlide function for 3 secs after clicking #Image1. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Answer is this

```
    function marginCalc(){
            var getmargin = parseInt($("#scrollimage").css('margin-left'));
            var usemargin =  -1350 ;
            var increment= getmargin+usemargin;
            if(increment <= -2750)
            {
            $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':0},1000);
            }
            else{
            $('#scrollimage').animate({'margin-left': ++increment},1000);
            }
        }


$(document).ready(function(){
        var autoslide = setInterval(marginCalc,5000);

        $("#Image1").click(function(){
                 clearInterval(autoSlide);
                $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':0}).delay(3000);
                 autoslide = setInterval(marginCalc,5000);
        });

        $("#Image2").click(function(){
                clearInterval(autoSlide);
                $("#scrollimage").animate({'margin-left':-1350}).delay(3000);
                autoslide = setInterval(marginCalc,5000);
        });

       });
```